# Where to start for editing order info?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I would like to change the way a shipping address is displayed in Magento, when viewing an order.
Since I'm not familiar with editing the adminhtml, nor the core of Mage, I'd like to know which file to refer to.
I'm currently viewing details in this file:

```
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

Line 170 reads:

```
<address><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true) ?></address>
```

This lead me to this file:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Which reads at line 948:

```
@return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address
```

So I opened the following file:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Address.php
```

Which extends:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php
```

In where the function format (Line 323) seems to do the trick.
But at that point, I end up with a renderer, but don't know how to continue. Could someone point me to the right file?

The thing I'm actually trying to do, is change the format of the shipping address from:

```
John Doe
Streetname 123
City, Postal
Country
T: Phone
```

To something like:

```
John Doe
Streetname 123
Postal, City
```

And in case a company was entered:

```
Companyname
to: John Doe
Streetname 123
Postal, City
```

Sorry for the long post, any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, but not in the Mage core!

Go to System > Configuration > Customer > Customer configuration > Address templates

I have changed the HTML output to the following:

```
{{if company}}{{var company}}<br />t.a.v.{{/if}}
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}} {{if city}}{{var city}}{{/if}}
```

Which is exactly what my client requested.